# SP 2010 Timer JOB not appearing in the Timer Job definitions under CA

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, powershell

I'm having a issue with One of my custom develop timer Jobs on SP2010 Farm.? Timer Job is not appearing in the Timer Job definitions under CA , Operations Tab

This timer Job is target scope on  web application  and attached to a subsite feature

I Check on the CA under -> Central administrator-> Solution Management

Timer job is listed as Status “Deployed” and with Deployed to “Web application”

When I run 
Get-SPTimerJob -webapplication "Web application name" 
Timer Job is listed with LastRunTime …

So fare I did 
//Deploy solution with CA

//Deployed Solution with PowerShell

01 Uninstall-SPSolution -Identity Solution.wsp -WebApplication "webapplication"

02 Remove-SPSolution -Identity  Solution.wsp –force

03 net stop sptimerv4
04 net start sptimerv4

06 Add-SPSolution e:\solutions\Solution.wsp

07 install-spsolution Solution.wsp -webapplication  "webapplication"    -GACDeployment –force

03 net stop sptimerv4
04 net start sptimerv4

05 iisreset

Enable -SPfeature Url xxxxxxxxxx -Identity XXXXXXXXXXXXXX -Force

Timer job is listed and running .. but  it's not visible on the Timer Job definitions under CA .. how to get Timer Job on to CA .

Appreciate  you help ..

Txn

Answer (score 2):

I think this maybe issue with SP FARM ...

Because of Foundation Web Application is not  running on the same server that CA runs there for web application features and/or timer jobs to remain hidden (not visible in the Central Administration web user interface).

Feature cannot be deployed globally.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj219591.aspx

Microsoft SharePoint Foundation Web Application

Front-end servers, batch-processing servers, plus the Distributed Cache and Request Management servers if these servers are implemented

This service provides web server functionality. It is started by default on web servers. Custom features scoped to web applications may not display in Central Administration as intended if this service is not started on the server running Central Administration and if the feature cannot be deployed globally.

i think i have to activate  Features a Web Front End server using stsadm

do you guys have any recommendation :/